# Converted Excel File removing leading zero

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file that has a Student ID on it. on csv file, some of the Student ID starts with 0 (eg. 00121334) the problem is, when I open the converted excel file, Excel removes all the leading zero which.
My question is how can I guaranteed that the excel does not remove all leading zero?
I've tried using this `destintationXLS.NumberFormat = "@";` but i'm not really sure where to put it.

here is my code:

```
public bool FormatInputToXLS(string CSVInputF1le, string XLSOutputFile, out string errormsg)
{
    bool isSuccess = faises
    errorMsg = string.Emptys
    Excel.Application xLApp2 = new Excel.Application();
    try
    {
        if(x1App2 == nu11)
        {
            x1App2 = new Excel.Application
            {
                Visible = true,
                DisplayAlerts = false,
                SheetsInNeuhlorkbook= 1
            };
        }
        bool fileExists =File.Exists(CSVInputFile);
        bool fileExists2 = File.Exists(XLSOutputFile);

        try
        {
            Excel.Workbook x1Book;
            Excel.Workbook x1Book2;
            xlBook = xLApp2.workbooks.Open(CSVInputFile);

            if(fileExists2)
                xlBook2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(xLSOutputFile);
            else
                xlBook2 = xLApp2.Workbooks.Add(missing);
            try
            {
                Excel.Worksheet x1Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Worksheet xlSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)x1Bool2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                xlSheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Student ID";

                int lastRow = 1;
                if(FileExists)
                {
                    int[] colsToCheck = { 1 };
                    List<int> nonEmpty = new List<int>();
                    for(int col = 0; col < colsToCheck.Length; col++)
                    {
                        nonEmpty.Add(((Excel.Range)x1Sheet.Cells[1, colsToCheck[col]]).End[Excel.X10irection.xlDown].Row);
                    }
                    lastRow = nonEmpty.Min();
                }

                Excel.Range sourceCSV = x1Sheet.get_Range(string.Concat("A1:A",lastRow));
                Excel.Range destintationXLS = x1Sheet2.Range["A2"];
                destintationXLS.NumberFormat = "@";
                sourceCSV.Copy();
                destintationXLS.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteSpecialType.xlPasteValues);

                for(int xlCol = 1; xlCol < xlSheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count; xlCol++)
                {
                    ((Excel.Range)xlSheet2.Cells[1,xlCol]).EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                }
                if (fileExists2)
                    xlBook2.Save();
                else
                    xlBook2.SaveAs(XLSOutputFile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing,missing,missing,missing,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing);
                    isSuccess = true;
                    xlBook.CLose(0);
                    xlBook2.Close(0);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                errorMsg = string.Concat("Failed to update file. ", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                xlBook.Close(0);
                xlBook2.Close(0);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            if (fileExists)
                errorMsg = string.Concat("Failed to open file. ", e1.Message);
            else    
                errorMsg = string.Concat("Failed to create file. ", e1.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
                CloseExcel(xlApp2)
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e2)
    {
        errorMsg = string.Concat("Failed to open Excel application. ", e2.Message);
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

ps. there are some typo on the code, the code works on my part. the problem is the leading zero

Comment: Make that ID column as a string column ie. '001234'. Then when you import it using your method above, you still have the leading 0

Comment: do you mean to make it as a string manually in the csv file? if that so, I can't do it since I have so many csv file

Comment: Yes I do, maybe you can do a replace in your files for some file pattern? maybe regex/simple find and replace to add ''

Comment: Maybe you could programmatically do it (to add '') ie. a VB script or console app or something OR a combination of this and find/replace

Comment: Regardless, you need to tell Excel that you column isnt a number, ensuring its a string stop this auto format on import and this is the best way of doing that

Answer (score 0):

A format won't really help in your case, since you need to change the underlying data type to text to lock in leading zeroes.

In the screenshot below, I've applied number format `00000` for a 5-digit format. This will fill with leading zeros, but the underlying value is still just the number `345`, as you can see in the formula bar for A1.

If you want to arrive at a true text value with leading zeros, you can use the TEXT() function. I've applied this formula to cell A3:

```
=TEXT(A2,"00000")
```

You could apply this function programatically in a new helper column, then copy the results and paste over the original number column using Paste Special > Values. After that, you can delete the helper column.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. the thing is I have so many data (ID) in csv file and some of them do not start with 0 and it doesn't have any fix format like it only contains 5 numbers. I checked my csv file and the ID with leading zero is formatted as text, but when it was converted excel read it as number.